# Store unexecuted function in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I am working with Greensock and trying to implement a CustomEase from stored JSON data. The issue I have is that when you add something to the timeline, you have to do it like this:

```
mainTimeline.to(target, duration, vars);
which would look like this:
mainTimeline.to($(".target", 1, {"opacity":"0","y":"35"});
```

The issue I have is that if you want to use easing, it has to be contained in the "vars" object, which would look like this:

```
mainTimeline.to(
    $(".target", 1, {
         "opacity":"0",
         "y":"35", 
         "ease": CustomEase.create('custom','M0,0,C0.104,0.204,0.492,1,1,1')
    });
```

The issue I am having is that when I store that data in JSON, I can store it as a string, but then when I insert it into the vars, it doesn't execute because it sees it as:

```
"CustomEase.create('custom','M0,0,C0.104,0.204,0.492,1,1,1')"
```

If however I store it as a function without quotes, what gets stored is the data that gets returned from the function:

```
{
    "_calcEnd": true,
    "id": "custom",
    "data": "M0,0,C0.104,0.204,0.492,1,1,1",
    "lookup": [
        {
            "x": 0,
            "cx": 0.017543859649122806,
            "y": 0,
            "cy": 0.0345276089301892,
            "nx": 9
        },
            [...]
        {
            "x": 0.017543859649122806,
            "cx": 0.017543859649122806,
            "y": 0.0345276089301892,
            "cy": 0.03419683114613436,
            "nx": 9
        }
    ],
    "points": [
        {
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "cx": 0.022788085937499997,
            "cy": 0.0448486328125,
            "n": {
                "x": 0.022788085937499997,
                "y": 0.0448486328125,
                "cx": 0.029204101562499998,
                "cy": 0.05669042968749999,
                "n": {
                    "x": 0.051992187499999995,
                    "y": 0.10153906249999999,
                    "cx": 0.0353798828125,
                    "cy": 0.06649902343749999,
                    },
                        [...]


                    "nx": 0.0873720703125
                },
                "nx": 0.051992187499999995
            },
            "nx": 0.022788085937499997
        },
        null,
        null,
        [...]
        null
    ],
    "fast": true,
    "rawBezier": [
        "0",
        "0",
        "0.104",
        "0.204",
        "0.492",
        "1",
        "1",
        "1"
    ],
    "l": 57
}"
```

How can I store this data in JSON that WILL get executed, just not till the Greensock function calls it like this without quotes:

`mainTimeline.to(
        $(".target", 1, {
             "opacity":"0",
             "y":"35", 
             "ease": CustomEase.create('custom','M0,0,C0.104,0.204,0.492,1,1,1')
        });`

Comment: You don't; JSON doesn't store functions. http://www.json.org/

Comment: Maybe I am explaining it poorly. I am not storing the actual function, just a reference to it, which needs to be returned without quotes.

Comment: You don't; JSON doesn't store references.

Comment: What I'm saying is that unless whatever is consuming the JSON knows to `eval` a string containing your code, you cannot do what you're asking for.

Comment: I am pretty sure it does use eval() but when I do a console.log on the vars I have stored in JSON it looks like this: `{ y: "-30px", ease: "CustomEase.create('custom', M0,0,C0…" }` I may have to do as you suggest and convert the entire thing to a string and loop through to concatenate it.

Comment: That would be the JSON representation, yes. What's *done* with that JSON is what matters.